# JavaScript linked to MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, google-maps

I have Google Maps with custom pins but the pins are programmed into the .js file.

I was hoping to be able to somehow link the javascript to a Database table in my MVC 4 Application, so that i could Add, Edit and Delete Pins without having to code them in.

Ideas?

This is the programmed code for 1 Marker:

```
//----Logo----//
var markerLogo= new google.maps.MarkerImage('images/administration.png',
new google.maps.Size(32, 37),
new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
new google.maps.Point(16, 37)
);


//----Content----//
var contentString = 'Contract';

//----Content-Link----//
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString
});

//----Marker-Position----//
var markerPos = new google.maps.LatLng(51.164999, -0.856703);
var markerInfo = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: markerPos,
    map: map,
    icon: markerLogo,
    title: "Contract"
});

//----Info-Function----//
google.maps.event.addListener(this, 'click', function () {
    open(map, this);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer, but try this. It works fine in my MVC 4 application

http://googlemapmvc.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it is what you need but you can look at [KnockoutMVC](http://knockoutmvc.com) project. This opensource framework allows generation of client-side code based on server side one (and yes, this is a product of our R&D department to be honest).